Не записывает в csv-файл
Это основной код откуда я вызываю insert.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas
import data_client


class Parser:
    links_to_parse = [
        'https://www.kufar.by/l/mebel',
        'https://www.kufar.by/l/mebel?cursor=eyJ0IjoiYWJzIiwiZiI6dHJ1ZSwicCI6MiwicGl0IjoiMjg1NTQzNzIifQ%3D%3D',
        'https://www.kufar.by/l/mebel?cursor=eyJ0IjoiYWJzIiwiZiI6dHJ1ZSwicCI6MywicGl0IjoiMjg1NTQzNzgifQ%3D%3D',
        'https://www.kufar.by/l/mebel?cursor=eyJ0IjoiYWJzIiwiZiI6dHJ1ZSwicCI6NSwicGl0IjoiMjg1NTQ1MDkifQ%3D%3D'
    ]
    data_client_imp = data_client.Sqlite3Client()

    @staticmethod
    def get_mebel_by_link(link):
        response = requests.get(link)
        mebel_data = response.text

        mebel_items = []
        to_parse = BeautifulSoup(mebel_data, 'html.parser')
        for elem in to_parse.find_all('a', class_='styles_wrapper__5FoK7'):
            try:
                price, description = elem.text.split('р.')
                mebel_items.append((
                    elem['href'],
                    int(price.replace(' ', '')),
                    description
                ))
            except:
                print(f'Цена не была указана. {elem.text}')

        return mebel_items

    @staticmethod
    def save_to_csv(mebel_items):
        pandas.DataFrame(mebel_items).to_csv('mebel.csv', index=False)

    def save_to_postgres(self, mebel_items):
        connection = self.data_client_imp.get_connection()
        self.data_client_imp.create_mebel_table(connection)
        for item in mebel_items:
            self.data_client_imp.insert(connection, item[0], item[1], item[2])

    def run(self):
        mebel_items = []
        for link in Parser.links_to_parse:
            mebel_items.extend(self.get_mebel_by_link(link))
        self.save_to_postgres(mebel_items)
        self.save_to_csv(mebel_items)

Parser().run()

Код модуля data_client:
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error
import psycopg2
import csv
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class DataClient(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def get_connection(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def create_mebel_table(self, conn):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def get_items(self, conn, price_from=0, price_to=100000):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def insert(self, conn, link, price, description):
        pass

    def run_test(self):
        conn = self.get_connection()
        self.create_mebel_table(conn)
        items = self.get_items(conn, price_from=10, price_to=30)
        for item in items:
            print(item)



    class CsvClient(DataClient):
    FILENAME = 'mebel.csv'

    def get_connection(self):
        return None

    def create_mebel_table(self, conn):
        pass

    def get_items(self, conn, price_from=0, price_to=100000):
        items = []
        with open(self.FILENAME, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
            file_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
            count = 0
            for row in file_reader:
                price = int(row[1])
                if count == 0:
                    print(f'Файл содержит столбцы: {",".join(row)}')
                elif not price <= price_from and price <= price_to:
                    items.append(row)
                count += 1
            return items

    def insert(self, conn, link, price, description):
        with open(self.FILENAME, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
            file_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=":", lineterminator="\r")
            file_writer.writerow(['link', 'price', 'description'])
            file_writer.writerow([f"'{link}', '{price}', '{description}'"])


data_client = CsvClient()
data_client.run_test()


А где у вас insert вызывается? Кроме того, вы в insert только заголовок пишете, данные не пишете. Добавьте код, как вы собственно тестируете, что вызываете.

Добавила и изменения в CsvClient тоже. Всё равно ничего  не записывается в файл. Insert даже не дебажится, чтоб посмотреть что не так и ошибок тоже не выдаёт. Просто читает и всё.

КАК ВЫ ВЫЗЫВАЕТЕ КОД, КОТОРЫЙ ПРИВЕДЁН В ВОПРОСЕ? И в приведённом вами коде метод insert нигде не вызывается.

Да я основной код добавила. Нужно было создать клиент для csv файла, что бы было чтение и запись csv файла. И чтение работает отлично, а вот запись как-то нет. Не понимаю почему.

Просто текстом запись делать, не вызывая link, price, description, тоже пробовала всё то же самое.

Может у вас в mebel_items просто пусто? Добавьте какую-то печать отладочную везде, чтобы понимать, что вызывается и как. И, повторюсь, при запуске run_test() у вас insert не вызывается.

Спасибо большое за помощь. Всё пишет.

with open('name_file.ext', mode="w", encoding='windows-1251') as w_file:
    file_writer = csv.writer(w_file, delimiter="|", lineterminator="\r")
    file_writer.writerow([data_for_write1])

Думаю mode='a' надо заменить на 'w'

пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Тоже пробовала, безрезультатно

Дело было в run_test. Я не вызвала там функцию.
